# Would a clock transported at relativistic speeds remain synchronized with a terrestrial reference?

Tags: special-relativity, time

I have two atomic clocks, and for the sake of the thought experiment, one is portable but in all other ways identical to a reference clock on Earth.  They have been perfectly synchronized to the best our near-future-FTL-capable-technology's ability.

I hop into my space ship, accelerate to 0.9c, travel to Earth's new colony on Alpha Centauri, decelerate, and walk on to the new world (which, oddly, smells like potato chips).

**Question:** Would my clocks still be perfectly synchronized?

Comment: How would you tell?

Comment: @probably_someone, while that is a very good question, it is outside the scope of my question.  But, if necessary, our intrepid adventurer can hop right back on the space ship and return to Earth to compare the two clocks.

Comment: At this point, you have just re-enacted the Twin Paradox, so you can just borrow conclusions from that thought experiment.

Comment: @probably_someone, OK, I just read through a summary of the Twin Paradox.  (Half the fun of physics is that turning a corner often bumps you into another issue.)  I'll recind my suggestion and leave the original question as it stands.  whether it's easy to prove empirically or not, would the two separated clocks remain synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

In special relativity, space and time are relative, i.e. they are perceived differently by observers that are in relative motion with respect to each other. And, when we say that "space and time are relative", we really mean it: [this relativity extends to the very notion of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

What that means is that different observers, in different states of motion, will legitimately disagree on whether two events that are happening in different locations - say, "clock A ticks noon on Earth" and "clock B ticks noon on Alpha Centauri" - are happening at the same time, or in which temporal order they happen. Moreover, because all physical reference frames are equivalent, there's no way to select an observer whose perspective is "right".

The upshot is that your question is actually ill-defined, and there's no meaningful way to even define the concept of clock synchronisation for spatially separated clocks without externally imposing a reference frame.

Comment: :-) "The upshot is that your question is actually ill-defined."  I appreciate that!  So, if I understand this correctly, it would be impossible for a space-faring society (as we understand the possibility today) to maintain time synchronization at all.  The best they could do is sync to "local time" at every destination?

Comment: One experiment to verify this is to send a signal from earth to alpha and one vice versa. Read the time of arrival and return this information to the sender. Then check if the arrival times match.

Comment: @JBH Yes and no - it's not "local Earth time", it's "Earth co-moving time", i.e. you can define a unique global time as seen by observers who are co-moving with the Earth. This will appear as gibberish to non-co-moving observers (they'll see some clocks as offset early and other clocks as offset late) but you can still make it work within that pre-specified (but otherwise non-special) reference frame.